How to bind an Angular signal/model to a template-driven <input> with an object as a value?
I'm trying to implement two-way binding in Angular18 by binding a property of an object within a signal (model) to ngModel. Specifically, I want to use a model signal as the source and ensure that changes update the corresponding property of the object and trigger signal notification cycle. However, the Angular documentation primarily shows examples with non-object signal values, which has left me confused about how to correctly modify object values.
Here are the approaches I've considered:

Here, I bind the ngModel directly to the properties of the signal's value object. While this allows me to modify the object properties and "updates" the object in the parent component, it does not notify consumers of signal changes. As a result, effect() and the output (personDataChange) will not be triggered.

<input [(ngModel)]="personData().firstName"/>
<input [(ngModel)]="personData().lastName"/>

personData = model.required<personData>();


Here, I use the (ngModelChange) event to manually update the signal. However, this feels too bulky, as I would need to implement this for every form field.

<input [ngModel]="personData().firstName"
       (ngModelChange)="update($event)"/>

update($event: string | undefined) {
  this.personData.update(value => ({...value, firstName: $event}));
}

So, my question is - is there another way of doing it so that the value would update and the update would notify consumers?
I would appreciate any suggestions on best practices for this usecase.

can you provide your effect() code and what you are trying to achieve. Perhaps there is another way to solve that.

@t-jami for example doing person search by firstName/lastName on every letter input

In your example, the two-way binding directly mutates the values inside signals without notifying the signal, which can cause issues where updates are not reflected correctly.
Signal works fine with [(ngModel)]="regularSignal" so there is no need for model input
Instead of passing a primitive value from the parent, you can pass an object containing signals, as shown below:
export class PersonalComponent {
  personData = input.required<{
    firstName: Signal<string>;
    lastName: Signal<string>;
  }>();

  _ = effect(() => {
    console.log(`[PERSONAL] Component ${this.personData().firstName()}`);
  });
}

ParentComponent
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [PersonalComponent],
  template: `
    <app-personal [personData]="pData" />
  `,
})
export class App {
  pData = { firstName: signal('ng'), lastName: signal('dev') };

  _ = effect(() => {
    console.log(`[APP] Component ${this.pData.firstName()}`);
  });
}

Working Example

Thank you for the good suggestion, I will consider it! However, I would need to create a mapper to convert every signal value into the combined object. I would have preferred a more automated approach. Perhaps signal input value transformations would be helpful here, but I'm not sure

@repi updated stackblitz please check

note this is some kind of design problem IMHO. Input signals are readonly by design, but someway the ngModel directive is changing its value. Probably a good use case for linkedSignal

Yea @Pizzicato i have posted answers before Linkedsignal was introduced but yea likedsign is good approach

@Pizzicato The Only caveat is that it would not trigger parent effect since we are dealing with normal values

@Chellappanவ I don't find that a caveat, actually, I think it's also a bad practice that a children component can modify parents data (it breaks the open/close principle). We have the model function for that, but I never use it for that reason, and rather use outputs to pass events to the parent to let it take care of whatever it needs to do with that output event and its passed data

@Pizzicato Yea I agree it will break open/close principle However Signals automatically notify all consumers (template bindings, computed signals, etc.) when their value changes in child

You might be looking for model signals.
import { JsonPipe } from '@angular/common';                                                              
import { Component, model } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
    
interface Data {
 name: string;
 value: number;
}
    
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [FormsModule, JsonPipe],
  template: `
<p>:{{ data() | json }}</p>
<p><input type="text" [(ngModel)]="data().name"></p>`,
  styleUrl: './app.component.scss'
})
export class AppComponent {
  data = model<Data>({ name: 'Otto', value: 10 });
}


yes, i was already using them personData = model.required<personData>();, but this approach would not trigger effect() or event output() of the model signal

You don't need to use signals with forms. Forms are already managing the change detection themselves.
Indeed, sometimes you can provide a signal to your ngModel, but you have to understand that it's to simplify updating your signal, and not to force you to use signals with forms.
By trying to do what you are doing, you are breaking the immutability of your signal, and it won't even work when you update an inner value.

Can you provide more information on signal immutability? I just was trying to replace the decorator-based @Input and @Output with Angular 18's input and output (model), which are now the recommended alternatives. So, if I am breaking the immutability by modifying signals value, am I forced to stick with the old API?

If you have a user = signal({ id: 1 }), and you do this.user().id = 2, that is breaking immutability. This will not trigger change detection. You could do this.user.update(u => u.id = 2), but I would still recommend to freeze your objects or type them as readonly, so that you avoid breaking immutability. Having an immutable state is often the base for state management librairies !
